# Dynamically instantiating an object in java

Tags: java, class, object, dynamic

I don't know if I have titled this correctly, but, I am looking for a way to instantiate a new object of a subclass based on user input. IE, I want to ask the user what sub class they want to create, and then create it based on that choice. So it may look like

```
 String category = CATEGORIES[Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine())];   
 items.add(new category(myString, myInt));
```

I am adding these into an ArrayList.

That new keyword seems to only accept an actual class though and not anything else. I have played around with built in Class methods but when i try to put those after the new call it fails. Pretty much anything I put after the new call except the class itself fails.

Is this something that is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for Reflection.

Comment: You could [instantiate the class using reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html). Or you could use a switch statement.

Comment: asking a user which class you have to instantiate is not really secure!

Comment: Check out the factory design pattern. It should get you exactly what you're looking for. [link](http://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/implementing-factory-design-pattern-in-java/)

Comment: Just going to go with a switch. I knew I could use that I was just looking for a "cleaner" way but the reflection thing looks way more complicated. 
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for reflection, and `Class.forName()` and `Class.forName().newInstance()`

Look: 
[What is the difference between "Class.forName()" and "Class.forName().newInstance()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-the-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstanc)

There is an example.

Look also:
[Initializing a class with Class.forName() and which have a constructor which takes arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658182/initializing-a-class-with-class-forname-and-which-have-a-constructor-which-tak)

Comment: I see what this is driving at, but I'm not clear on how to make it actually work. Will this method still work if I have constructors on my subclasses?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend this, but it is possible with Reflection:

```
Object thing = Class.forName(category).getConstructor().newInstance();
```

This gets the class with the name stored in `category`, gets its no-argument constructor, and invokes it, storing the resulting `Object` in `thing`.

A lot can go wrong here; this will only work if none of the following are true:

- There is no class with the given name.
- The user says something like "String" instead of "java.lang.String".  `Class.forName(String s)` only works with fully qualified names.
- The class has no nullary constructor (a constructor that takes no arguments).

Also, as someone mentioned, this is a *very* insecure and unstable thing to do.

Comment: Would there be a way to do this if i have a constructor that requires fields?

Comment: Yes.  Look at the Javadocs here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...) and here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Category {}
public class Foo extends Category { public Foo(String s, int i) {}}
public class Bar extends Category { public Bar(String s, int i) {}}
String[] CATEGORIES = { Foo.class.getName(), Bar.class.getName() };
static final Class<?>[] ARGTYPES = { String.class, int.class };
```

and

```
List<Category> items = new ArrayList<>();
String category = CATEGORIES[Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine())];   
items.add((Category)Class.forName(category)
    .getConstructor(ARGTYPES)
    .newInstance(myString, myInt));
```