# Initialize A Class by Class.forName with Array type parameters

Tags: java, class, parameters, initialization

I have a class with a constructor that I need to initialize by name.

```
public class Wall extends Tile 
{
    public Wall(double x, double y, double[] data) 
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

the Tile is an abstract class, and it's constructor is empty.

I can initialize this class with

```
Class.forName("Wall").newInstance();
```

And if I want to pass Parameters through when I initiate the class, I can use

```
Constructor<?> c = Class.forName("Wall").getConstructor(param);

c.newInstance(Paramater values ie. "String");
```

As for the `param`, it depends on what type of parameter you are passing through.

`int`: `Integer.TYPE`

`double` : `Double.TYPE`

`String` : `String.class`

this post on stackoverflow helped me with those parameters
[Initializing a class with Class.forName() and which have a constructor which takes arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658182/initializing-a-class-with-class-forname-and-which-have-a-constructor-which-tak)

But the question I have is how can I pass through Array parameters. ie a `double[]`?

I've tried `Double[].class`, but that threw a `ThreadNotFoundException`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you submit the "NAME" class? Or at least post its constructor code

Comment: Yes. That would be useful for context. Post has been updated to include the class.

Comment: i suppose the real question over here is "why?".
you're making your code super complicated, using the approach that would generally be frowned upon in the world of Java. Explain why you're doing this and perhaps we can find a way to make it simpler?

Comment: I have explained what I need help with in my post. I don't need to explain "why" I'm doing it this way. I just am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might there be a better way. But I've tested that and it works:

```
Constructor<?> constr = Class.forName("Wall").getDeclaredConstructor(Double.TYPE, Double.TYPE, (new double[] {}).getClass());
double x = 1;
double y = 2;
double[] data = new double[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
Wall obj = (Wall) constr.newInstance( x , y, data );
```